# Combobox does not select value on edit action, Rails and Semantic-ui

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, semantic-ui

What is the bet way to integrate [semant-ui dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) with Rails way?

When i takes to edit action, it does not bring the status selected,

On index, create, show, even update its ok.

I know how to do do it with jQuery, but i dont know if maybe there is a rails way to do it and would like to know how you ninjas would do it?

```
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <%= f.hidden_field :status  %>
    <div class="default text">Status</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <%= content_tag :div, :status, class: 'menu' do %>
      <% Task::STATUSES.each do |s| %>
        <div class="item" data-value="<%= s %>"><%= s %></div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

See [app runnnig](http://todo-ror.herokuapp.com/tasks/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Well for the dropdown that you are trying to create, a better rails way of doing would be something like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <label>Status</label>
    <%= f.select(:status,options_for_select(Task::STATUSES.all.collect{|x| [x.name,x.id,class:'item']}),{prompt:'your Status'},class:'ui dropdown')%>

</div>
```